# what syntax/code html use to solved this?

Tags: html, list, multiple-columns

Please help me find the html codes to put the list on the right side of the page. I already tried to use css but the code doesn't work

[image: i don't know how to put the "home,archives.." to the right upper side of the page]

Can you tell me what syntax i should use to make the "home,archives..." to the right side of the page.

I made this one

[image: this the remake i make]

```css
#konten {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 13pt;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="navbar.png" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
</nav>
<p>AUGUST 9, 2005, <time>5:04</time> PM EDT</p>

<h1>I'm hungry</h1>

<p>Strange. I seem to get hungry about the same time every<br> day. Maybe it's something in the water.</p>

<hr align="left" width="30%">

<p>AUGUST 6, 2005, <time>5:12</time> PM </p>

<h1>When's dinner?</h1>

<p>My gastric juices are gurgling...</p>

<p>I'll write more later!</p>

<div class="col-9 col-m-7">
  <div id="konten">
    <div class="col-12 col-m-12">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a>Archives</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">August 2005</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">July 2005</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">may 2005</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should try to post all your code, its hard to see what the problem is with partial code

Comment: A bit off-topic, but what is this resource you're learning from? it looks ancient and the dates confirm it. Also, the top screenshot looks like, I honestly don't know. For now add all your code and what you tried, you mentioned you tried CSS but without seeing it we can't say what the problem is, you'll also need to include the whole HTML

Comment: @RaymondNgule sorry. i already update the code

Comment: @Buttered_Toast , sorry . i update the code, please check

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Note that the attributes you use on the `<hr>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more.

Answer (score 0):

youn need to put the code that you want to be side by side in a container, then turn the container into a flexbox by adding `display: flex` in css,

make sure that the stuff you want to be on the right is in its own container
and the stuff you want to be on the left is in its on container.

if you want to add space between the 2 containers (the left and right containers) add this css to conater class

`justify-content: space-between` this will put the elements on opposit ends

`justify-content: space-around` this will add equal space around the containers

if you wan just a bit of space this css will help

```
#konten{
  margin-left: 20px
}
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex; /*set the disp-lay of the cotainer to flex*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> <!-- create a main container that will house all the code you want to separate -->
   
   <div><!-- create a container for the stuff that will be on the right  -->
    <nav>
        <img src="navbar.png"style="margin-left: 10px;" />
    </nav>
    <p>AUGUST 9, 2005, <time>5:04</time> PM EDT</p>

    <h1>I'm hungry</h1>

    <p>Strange. I seem to get hungry about the same time every<br> day. Maybe it's something in the water.</p>

    <hr align="left" width="30%">

    <p>AUGUST 6, 2005, <time>5:12</time> PM </p>

    <h1>When's dinner?</h1>

    <p>My gastric juices are gurgling...</p> 

    <p>I'll write more later!</p>
   </div>

    <div class="col-9 col-m-7"> <!-- this will be the container for the stuff that will be on the right -->
        <div id="konten">
            <div class="col-12 col-m-12">
                <ul id="menu" >
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>Archives</a>
                        <ul>
                             <li><a href="#">August 2005</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">July 2005</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">may 2005</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: heyy thank for helping me, one more thing please,
i already try the code that you make, and how can i make the list thing a little bit to the right?

Comment: i made som changes to the answer folowing your changes to the post, on how you can add space check the answer, it has that info

Comment: The attributes you use on the `<hr>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for 15 years or more.

Comment: @rob i just copied the code he sent and provided the solution he was requesting for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you might be using Bootstrap. If that's the case, place the following in the `<head>`

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The most basic layout you'll use with Bootstrap is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">This takes up 6 column spaces -- half of ".row"</div>
    <div class="col-6">Same as previous sibling div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

| Bootstrap Class | Position |
| --- | --- |
| ``` container ``` | Wrap around `".row"` tags. |
| ``` row ``` | Wrap around `".col-*"` tags. |
| ``` col-* ``` | Wrap around content. `*` is a number in the range of 1 to 12. |

### Example A

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <header class="col-12">
      <h1>Example A</h1>
      <p>This header takers up all 12 column spaces.</p>
    </header>
  </div>
  <main class="row">
    <section class="col-7">
      <h2>Section</h2>
      <p>This section takes up 7 out of 12 column spaces.</p>
    </section>
    <nav class="col-5">
      <h2>Nav</h2>
      <menu>
        <li>This section takes up 5 out of 12 column spaces.
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </menu>
    </nav>
  </main>
</div>
```

### Example B

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="row">
      <h1>Hunger Blog</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <main class="col-9">
        <section>
          <p>AUGUST 9, 2005, <time>5:04</time> PM EDT</p>

          <h2>I'm Hungry</h2>

          <p>Strange. I seem to get hungry about the same time every<br> day. Maybe it's something in the water.</p>
        </section>
        <hr align="left" width="30%">
        <section>
          <p>AUGUST 6, 2005, <time>5:12</time> PM </p>

          <h2>When's Dinner?</h2>

          <p>My gastric juices are gurgling...</p>

          <p>I'll write more later!</p>
        </section>
      </main>

      <nav class="col-3">
        <menu>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a>Archives</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">August 2005</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">July 2005</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">May 2005</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </menu>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```